# How to debug Django request "POST /url/ HTTP/1.1" 400

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-debug-toolbar

I am using django + django-rest-framework

I am sending POST request from ios app to the python server locally and got 400 error code. I got that the problem is in the json body that I send and I want to output somewhere the full POST request but I have no luck.

```
[13/Jan/2016 22:48:45] "POST /url/ HTTP/1.1" 400 75
```

I don't understand how to print anything after I runserver (the simplest way). Is it even possible?

I've tried to enable [logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/logging/) in the settings but also had no luck.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'console':{
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers':['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        }
    },
}

import logging.config
logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

I also installed [django debug toolbar](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/) but it also doesn't show requests that I send.
Also I've tried to return HttpResponse but still hadn't got POST request data.

What is the way to output somewhere requests data (console, file or anything else) in the django or django-rest-framework?

**FIXED:**

I've added Middleware in views.py that extends my console output like this:

```
class ExceptionLoggingMiddleware(object):
def process_request(self, request):
    print request.body
    print request.scheme
    print request.method
    print request.META
    return None
```

and don't forget to add this Middleware to your settings file like this

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
'movie.views.ExceptionLoggingMiddleware']
```

Also as I understand LOGGING that I've created through the settings file worked but it was outputting not a large amount of info, just some sql warnings.

Comment: Error logging, you should expand on how you set up your logging and what "no luck" entailed

Comment: Make sure you have set [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) in your settings.

Comment: @Sayse I've edited description. By no luck I mean that there is no debug info in the console except `[13/Jan/2016 22:48:45] "POST /url/ HTTP/1.1" 400 75`

Answer (score 4):

The quick'n'dirty way of doing this is adding debugging to the entry point of the request handler. In In `DjangoRestFramework` classes, as well as in `Django` class based views this entry point is the `dispatch()` method.

You can do something like:

```
class MyView(View):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace() # or print debug statements
        super(MyView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This answer is good because it runs before the permission_classes so you can inspect the request.headers to see what is making it there.

Answer (score 3):

### An answer for `Django 4` and `Python3.8`

**tl;dr**

In your `views.py` put this:

```
class ExceptionLoggingMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.
        print(request.body)
        print(request.scheme)
        print(request.method)
        print(request.META)

        response = self.get_response(request)

        return response
```

and this in your `settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'myproject.myapp.views.ExceptionLoggingMiddleware',
    # ...
    # ...
    # ... -- all the other Middleware entries that has already been there ...
    # ...
    # ...
]
```

---

### The detailed description

Project structure for this example:

```
.
├── README.md
├── myproj
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── myapp
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── serializers.py
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py <-- This is where you put the middleware code
│   ├── settings.py <-- This is where you "import" the middleware
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
...
```

#### Example output in the application log

```
Bad Request: /api/measure/
[23/Feb/2022 22:21:19] "POST /api/measure/ HTTP/1.1" 400 592
b'{"buf_out":"23.0", "buf_p3":"30.0", "buf_p2":"0.0"}'
http
POST
{'PATH': '/Users/ ... AND A LOT OF OTHER METADATA STUFF .., 'wsgi.run_once': False, 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http', 'wsgi.multithread': True, 'wsgi.multiprocess': False, 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class 'wsgiref.util.FileWrapper'>}
```

#### The reason for the update of the answer

I believe that @Roberto's answer to his own question was the best one. However, the way to implement the middleware has changed since 2016, see the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware

Hence my update.

### Additional materials

In my case, the complete `MIDDLEWARE` variable is:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'myproj.myapp.views.ExceptionLoggingMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

There is actually no need to setup the `LOGGING` variable in `settings.py` for this to work.

---

Before you will hate for digging out a "dead" question, please note that:

1. This is the first question that appears after searching for "django debug rest in response body" in the Google.
2. This question has been viewed over 7k times since 2016, so obviously there is still a living interest in this question.
3. The "Edit queue" for the question itself is full :(

Answer (score 1):

This was  my solution, inspired by this blog post on error handling in  django rest framework (https://commitcode.com/custom-error-handler-in-django-rest-framework)

Personally, I use Sentry (https://sentry.com) to capture my exceptions. But you can follow the logic and put in anything you want.

First, I create a custom exception handler which I then wire-up using Django Rest Framework's settings.

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ..settings...
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'myapp.exception_handler_400.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

Next, I created the file which will handle the actual exception. It simply fires any existing logic, then checks if the error was 400. If so, then it fires the exception up to Sentry.

**myapp.exception_handler_400**

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler
from raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.models import client

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    if response is not None:

        if response.status_code == 400:
            client.captureException()

    return response
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to **put the text you need** to see directly **to error message** which is returned with HTTP 400. To achieve it you have to create your custom handler for http 400 errors in Django.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include('myproject.urls_api')),
]

handler400 = 'project.error_handlers.bad_request'
```

**error_handlers.py**

```
from django import http
from django.conf import settings

def bad_request(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return http.HttpResponseBadRequest(
        '<h1>Bad Request (400), DEUBG DATA: {}</h1>'.format(settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS),
        content_type='text/html')
```

In my case, the problem was with wrong ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py

Answer (score 0):

If you run your server locally for development, I would recommend using [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/). It has build-in Django support (in pro version) so you can start your server in the debug mode. Even if you will not buy it, you'll have 30-day trial. Should be enough to find out what the problem is.